# Counting text strings containing >, < or =

Tags: excel

I am trying to count the number of cells that contains text using `>` or `<`. 
I have a  list that indicates time in years:

`Y1:Y3 = (<2years, <5 years, <10 years)`.

If I use `COUNT.IF(A4:H4; S4)` where `S4` points to `Y1 [=Y1]` then this returns a number that counts all cells with text - incorrect!

Is there any secure way to do this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results.  What version of Excel is using `COUNT.IF`?  Mine uses `COUNTIF`.  What is in A4:H4?  I only get a count, using `COUNTIF` and your formula, if the entire string you indicate populates the Y1:Y3 range is in one of those cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIF` together with strings containing wildcards:

[image]

In this example I had the formulas

```
=COUNTIF(A1:B4,"=*<*")
=COUNTIF(A1:B4,"=*>*")
=COUNTIF(A1:B4,"=*=*")
```

in cells A7 to C7, respectively.

If you have cells that contain e.g. `<=` then those cells will be counted twice (once as a cell containing `<` and once as a cell containing `=`). If this is an issue you could possibly use similar countifs to count the number of cells that contain various combinations of `<,>,=` and use these counts to correct your overall count.